# Does maxDegreeOfParallelism stop every other Parallel.ForEach from doing creating new tasks?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

If there are two `Parallel.ForEach` loops with `maxDegreOfParallelism = 3`, will both only run 3 threads?

OR

Can we restrict the number of threads are generated to a specific number?

I have a code in which I require `Parallel.ForEach` twice, they only have a task.Start() call.

My question is if I specify in both `Parallel.ForEach` loops that `maxDegreeOfParallelism = 3`, does that apply in general? That is, will the other `Parallel.ForEach` not invoke an action if already 3 threads will be running?

This is just a demo type code, not the real thing. For reasons, I'd prefer not to share the actual function. Only the `subTasks.Add(() => {})` portion is different, rest is the same.

```
    async static void myFunction()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int m = i + 1;
            List<Task> subTasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                int n = j + 1;
                subTasks.Add(new Task(async () => {
    //the actual work i want done will go in here
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing Task " + m + "." + n);
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Completed Task " + m + "." + n);
                }));
            }

            tasks.Add(new Task(async () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing Task " + m);
                Parallel.ForEach(subTasks, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, 
                    subTask => {
                    subTask.Start();
                });
                await Task.WhenAll(subTasks);
                Console.WriteLine("Completed Task " + m);
            }));
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(tasks, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, task => { task.Start(); });
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

I want the `Parallel.ForEach` loop to not invoke more actions if a total of 3 threads are running.

Also, if there is an alternate way of doing this, I'll be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: async and Parallel.* don't mix well. Using Parallel.ForEach() to _start_ tasks seems very unnecessary and unwise.

Comment: And the outer function is `async void`, that is probably not what you need/want.

Comment: The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` refers to that specific `Parallel.ForEach` loop. So if you have two running with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3` it can run 3x2 concurrent operations.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for the response. async was so that I could call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. So I should go for the `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())` right? Because I want to wait for all the tasks to finish before I proceed.

Comment: @404 Thank you for your response. That was the thing I was having trouble understanding.

Comment: `That is, will the other Parallel.ForEach not invoke an action if already 3 threads will be running?` No.